# How to query to see the attributes in the views of Marketing list in CRM?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm

I would like to fetch the attribute names like Listname,type,member type as shown in fig:
[image]

I used the following query:

```
SELECT Name,
       *
FROM SavedQuery
WHERE ReturnedTypeCode = 4300
      AND StateCode = 0
      AND Name LIKE 'Active Marketing Lists%'
```

Comment: What happens when you run this query?

Comment: Just returns the view name,createdby,modifiedby,fetchxml,layoutxml.

Comment: We can't see your screen and have no idea what your tables are like. And sadly you haven't asked a question. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You have to query from `list` entity, that will result the needed columns of **Marketing List**.

```
SELECT listname, purpose, listid, membertype, type, lastusedon
FROM list
ORDER BY listname DESC
```

`SavedQuery` is view definition stored in DB like **Active Marketing Lists**.

Update:

The view columns which are designed/defined in view will be stored in layoutxml & layoutjson columns of `savedquery` records.

Comment: I would like to see the columns in views like Active marketing lists, inactive marketing list as part of UI testing

Comment: @user3331421 those will be stored in layoutjson, layoutxml columns.. it will be rendered in UI..

Comment: Thank you. I found it in layout xml